# Raise a Latex symbol above the sentence baseline

Tags: formatting

When I type `$\chi$` it is set too low, such that it looks like a subscript: `$K \chi$`. How can I raise it to the same height as other symbols?

Comment: `\raisebox{2pt}{$\chi$}`

Comment: It isn't a subscript.  I want it to read KX, not Kx.  It just LOOKS like a subscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could raise the `\chi` symbol by its depth with a `\raisebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\raisedchi}{\raisebox{\depth}{\(\chi\)}}
\begin{document}
\(xyz\chi\) \(xyz\raisedchi\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would not recommend to do that since the greek letter chi is *supposed* to go below the baseline. Maybe you're looking for a calligraphic X or something else.

Comment: What do you mean "supposed to"?  You mean if I'm writing in Greek?  No worries there. :)

Comment: @MrUser No, the letter *is* expected to go below the baseline. Readers will mistake it for X.

Comment: @MrUser chi is a letter, it's just the way it is usually written. Raising a chi on the baseline is just like raising a lowercase y on the baseline.

Comment: You would not rise the Latin letters "g" or "y", neither.